# How to update _id to be username for all documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d33d5dbec0888024d48c02c"),
    "username" : "John",
    "city" : "London"
}, 

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d33ddebec0888024d48c0cb"),
    "username" : "Ej",
    "city" : "London"
}
```

I'm new in mongo and I'm trying to make username as _id for all documents which is unique value. I would like it to be:

```
{
    "_id" : "John",
    "id" : "5d33d5dbec0888024d48c02c",
    "city" : "London"
}, 

{
    "_id" : "Ej",
    "id" : "5d33ddebec0888024d48c0cb",
    "city" : "London"
}
```

So, is there any query to do this?

Comment: you can update the _id in mongodb to different format other than ObjectId() but there will be problem if you want to order the data asc and desc by timestamp. if you want to make username become unique i suggest you use index like this  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/